# Why does my integer menu work but not my character menu?

Tags: c

Here is my integer menu that works as desired:
https://gist.github.com/hisgotthewholeworld/81d2d96a7a4736d85c22b28d5bf36435

Here is my character menu that doesn't work as desired:
https://gist.github.com/hisgotthewholeworld/36ae2b9b7546cc0af627d399c82c7177

My character menu is using the selected case when inputted but is then immediately using the default case. My integer array seems to work fine however and I've done everything I know of to convert it to work with characters. Any help would be very appreciated. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char read_number(void);

int main(void)
{
  char choice;
  printf("Make a choice\n");

  while ((choice = read_number())!= '5')
  {
    switch (choice)
    {
      case '1' :
        printf("Choice 1\n");
        printf("Make a choice\n");
        break;
      case '2' :
        printf("Choice 2\n");
        printf("Make a choice\n");
        break;
      case '3' :
        printf("Choice 3\n");
        printf("Make a choice\n");
        break;
      case '4' :
        printf("Choice 4\n");
        printf("Make a choice\n");
        break;
      default :
        printf("Invalid choice\n");
        break;
    }
  }

  return 0;
}

char read_number (void)
{
  char num;
  scanf("%c", &num);
  return num;
}
```

This is also the output I'm getting:

Make a choice

**1**

Choice 1

Make a choice

Invalid choice

**2**

Choice 2

Make a choice

Invalid choice

**3**

Choice 4

Make a choice

Invalid choice

**4**

Choice 4

Make a choice

Invalid choice

**5**

Comment: Please post your code here directly.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (of the *failing* program) and post it *in* the question.

Comment: Your character menu works FINE either on my comp

Comment: Because `%c` does not skip white space but `%d` does.

Comment: Tip: make error messages more informative: `printf("Invalid choice %d <%c>\n", choice, choice);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At every new iteration `scanf("%c", &num);` is reading trailing carriage returns, this causes default case to execute, write it as `scanf(" %c", &num);`.

Answer (score 3):

It is not working because the `char` is getting the new line (enter key), use 
`char num = getchar();` 
to get just the key.

Answer (score 0):

Try using fflush(stdin) . the input buffer that got '1\n' each time still holds the '\n' for the next while loop and in that second loop for each try goes in the loop and sends the default message. you can instead also add another switch case for the  '\n' condition that passes its turn on 
.

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` is not guaranteed to work in all implementations: the C Standard even has that as an [explicit example of Undefined Behaviour](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#J.2).